How to connect to Tor as transparent proxy?
Context
As briefly aforediscussed at discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/71827/9 (paraphrased to redact irrelevant content):


I, very recently, installed tor-0.4.8.13-1.fc41.x86_64, hoping to access *.onion domains via firefox-133.0-2.fc41.x86_64 (with "network.dns.blockDotOnion": false in about:config).

However, check.torproject.org informs me that I'm not connected, and running tor on the CLI displays the undermentioned even with the service enabled:

RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ sudo dnf install tor
Updating and loading repositories:
Repositories loaded.
Package                                                                                                       Arch                   Version                                                                                                       Repository                                                           Size
Installing:
 tor                                                                                                          x86_64                 0.4.8.13-1.fc41                                                                                               updates                                                          27.5 MiB
Installing dependencies:
 torsocks                                                                                                     x86_64                 2.4.0-7.fc41                                                                                                  fedora                                                          156.6 KiB

Transaction Summary:
 Installing:         2 packages

Total size of inbound packages is 4 MiB. Need to download 4 MiB.
After this operation, 28 MiB extra will be used (install 28 MiB, remove 0 B).
Is this ok [y/N]: y
[1/2] torsocks-0:2.4.0-7.fc41.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                100% | 232.2 KiB/s |  67.8 KiB |  00m00s
[2/2] tor-0:0.4.8.13-1.fc41.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  100% |   3.3 MiB/s |   4.2 MiB |  00m01s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2/2] Total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         100% |   1.5 MiB/s |   4.3 MiB |  00m03s
Running transaction
[1/4] Verify package files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          100% | 222.0   B/s |   2.0   B |  00m00s
[2/4] Prepare transaction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           100% |   7.0   B/s |   2.0   B |  00m00s
[3/4] Installing torsocks-0:2.4.0-7.fc41.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     100% |   2.9 MiB/s | 159.4 KiB |  00m00s
[4/4] Installing tor-0:0.4.8.13-1.fc41.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       100% |  34.7 MiB/s |  27.5 MiB |  00m01s
Complete!
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ systemctl status tor
○ tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf, 50-keep-warm.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ tor
Dec 12 21:29:36.217 [notice] Tor 0.4.8.13 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.2.2, Zlib 1.3.1.zlib-ng, Liblzma 5.6.2, Libzstd 1.5.6 and Glibc 2.40 as libc.
Dec 12 21:29:36.217 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Dec 12 21:29:36.217 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [warn] Directory /run/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [warn] Before Tor can create a control socket in "/run/tor/control", the directory "/run/tor" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user and group account that is running Tor.  (On some Unix systems, anybody who can list a socket can connect to it, so Tor is being careful.)
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Dec 12 21:29:36.218 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ systemctl start tor
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ systemctl status tor
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf, 50-keep-warm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-12-12 21:30:39 GMT; 2s ago
 Invocation: 0154028dfaa34c2eab5a4957c6e80a50
    Process: 603427 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 603428 (tor)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 37170)
     Memory: 36.9M (peak: 38.1M)
        CPU: 234ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
             └─603428 /usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc

Dec 12 21:30:40 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Dec 12 21:30:40 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection
Dec 12 21:30:40 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus
Dec 12 21:30:40 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 40% (loading_keys): Loading authority key certs
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services.
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 45% (requesting_descriptors): Asking for relay descriptors
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/7925, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.)
Dec 12 21:30:41 SNRW3Q Tor[603428]: Bootstrapped 50% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ tor
Dec 12 21:30:56.810 [notice] Tor 0.4.8.13 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.2.2, Zlib 1.3.1.zlib-ng, Liblzma 5.6.2, Libzstd 1.5.6 and Glibc 2.40 as libc.
Dec 12 21:30:56.810 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Dec 12 21:30:56.810 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [warn] Directory /run/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [warn] Before Tor can create a control socket in "/run/tor/control", the directory "/run/tor" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user and group account that is running Tor.  (On some Unix systems, anybody who can list a socket can connect to it, so Tor is being careful.)
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Dec 12 21:30:56.811 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.




I'm surprised by this, because neither the internet nor CLI appear to provide any clear instructions on how to configure this.

I've since been able to restart the service, and its logs appear to demonstrate accomplishment in its connection to the network, (in the stead of the aforementioned failure):


#!/usr/bin/env sh
systemctl start tor && \
systemctl status tor



● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf, 50-keep-warm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-12-12 23:23:39 GMT; 5s ago
 Invocation: d99680d74dad44128ac91f4b15485446
    Process: 655421 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 655429 (tor)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 37170)
     Memory: 105.9M (peak: 122M)
        CPU: 473ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
             └─655429 /usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc

Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Opened Control listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/control
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
Dec 12 23:23:40 SNRW3Q Tor[655429]: Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done




However, check.torproject.org continues to state the undermentioned - that I am not connected:

Sorry. You are not using Tor.

I have located some instructions at discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/71827/3, whose author reliably purports can remediate this:

sudo dnf install tor
sudo tee /etc/tor/custom.torrc << EOF > /dev/null
TOR_CONFIG_OPTIONS
EOF
sudo systemctl --now enable tor@custom.service


However, I've little understanding of what it does (excepting what I've been able to learn from an LLM's comprehension of it) and I've no confirmation from any official source.
Questions

Do official configuration instructions exist?
If so, what are these?

Environment


#!/usr/bin/env sh
kinfo



Operating System : Fedora Linux 41
Kernel Version   : 6.11.10-300.fc41.x86_64 (64-bit)
Processors       : 12 × AMD Ryzen 5 7600X 6-Core Processor
Memory           : 30.4 GiB of RAM




TorRC
To ascertain which are available, I utilized locate (as askubuntu.com/questions/632238/where-is-torcc-for-tor-browser-in-ubuntu-14-04#comment900307_632238 advises):


#!/usr/bin/env sh
locate -b '*[t]orrc'

[1]


/etc/tor/torrc
/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc




Their contents are undermentioned:

/etc/tor/torrc

## Configuration file for a typical Tor user
## Last updated 28 February 2019 for Tor 0.3.5.1-alpha.
## (may or may not work for much older or much newer versions of Tor.)
##
## Lines that begin with "## " try to explain what's going on. Lines
## that begin with just "#" are disabled commands: you can enable them
## by removing the "#" symbol.
##
## See 'man tor', or https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html,
## for more options you can use in this file.
##
## Tor will look for this file in various places based on your platform:
## https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-editing-torrc/

ControlSocket /run/tor/control
ControlSocketsGroupWritable 1
CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFile /run/tor/control.authcookie
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1

## Tor opens a SOCKS proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't
## configure one below. Set "SOCKSPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only
## as a relay, and not make any local application connections yourself.
#SOCKSPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
#SOCKSPort 192.168.0.1:9100 # Bind to this address:port too.

## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SOCKSPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SOCKSPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SOCKSPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
#SOCKSPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
#SOCKSPolicy accept6 FC00::/7
#SOCKSPolicy reject *

## Logs go to stdout at level "notice" unless redirected by something
## else, like one of the below lines. You can have as many Log lines as
## you want.
##
## We advise using "notice" in most cases, since anything more verbose
## may provide sensitive information to an attacker who obtains the logs.
##
## Send all messages of level 'notice' or higher to /var/log/tor/notices.log
#Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
## Send every possible message to /var/log/tor/debug.log
#Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
## Use the system log instead of Tor's logfiles
#Log notice syslog
## To send all messages to stderr:
#Log debug stderr

## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
#RunAsDaemon 1

## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows.
#DataDirectory /var/lib/tor

## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
#ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
#CookieAuthentication 1

############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###

## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22

################ This section is just for relays #####################
#
## See https://community.torproject.org/relay for details.

## Required: what port to advertise for incoming Tor connections.
#ORPort 9001
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## ORPort (e.g. to advertise 443 but bind to 9090), you can do it as
## follows.  You'll need to do ipchains or other port forwarding
## yourself to make this work.
#ORPort 443 NoListen
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise
## If you want to listen on IPv6 your numeric address must be explicitly
## between square brackets as follows. You must also listen on IPv4.
#ORPort [2001:DB8::1]:9050

## The IP address or full DNS name for incoming connections to your
## relay. Leave commented out and Tor will guess.
#Address noname.example.com

## If you have multiple network interfaces, you can specify one for
## outgoing traffic to use.
## OutboundBindAddressExit will be used for all exit traffic, while
## OutboundBindAddressOR will be used for all OR and Dir connections
## (DNS connections ignore OutboundBindAddress).
## If you do not wish to differentiate, use OutboundBindAddress to
## specify the same address for both in a single line.
#OutboundBindAddressExit 10.0.0.4
#OutboundBindAddressOR 10.0.0.5

## A handle for your relay, so people don't have to refer to it by key.
## Nicknames must be between 1 and 19 characters inclusive, and must
## contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9].
## If not set, "Unnamed" will be used.
#Nickname ididnteditheconfig

## Define these to limit how much relayed traffic you will allow. Your
## own traffic is still unthrottled. Note that RelayBandwidthRate must
## be at least 75 kilobytes per second.
## Note that units for these config options are bytes (per second), not
## bits (per second), and that prefixes are binary prefixes, i.e. 2^10,
## 2^20, etc.
#RelayBandwidthRate 100 KBytes  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
#RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KBytes # But allow bursts up to 200KB (1600Kb)

## Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
## Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
## not to their sum: setting "40 GB" may allow up to 80 GB total before
## hibernating.
##
## Set a maximum of 40 gigabytes each way per period.
#AccountingMax 40 GBytes
## Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
#AccountingStart day 00:00
## Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
## is per month)
#AccountingStart month 3 15:00

## Administrative contact information for this relay or bridge. This line
## can be used to contact you if your relay or bridge is misconfigured or
## something else goes wrong. Note that we archive and publish all
## descriptors containing these lines and that Google indexes them, so
## spammers might also collect them. You may want to obscure the fact that
## it's an email address and/or generate a new address for this purpose.
##
## If you are running multiple relays, you MUST set this option.
##
#ContactInfo Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>
## You might also include your PGP or GPG fingerprint if you have one:
#ContactInfo 0xFFFFFFFF Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>

## Uncomment this to mirror directory information for others. Please do
## if you have enough bandwidth.
#DirPort 9030 # what port to advertise for directory connections
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## DirPort (e.g. to advertise 80 but bind to 9091), you can do it as
## follows.  below too. You'll need to do ipchains or other port
## forwarding yourself to make this work.
#DirPort 80 NoListen
#DirPort 127.0.0.1:9091 NoAdvertise
## Uncomment to return an arbitrary blob of html on your DirPort. Now you
## can explain what Tor is if anybody wonders why your IP address is
## contacting them. See contrib/tor-exit-notice.html in Tor's source
## distribution for a sample.
#DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html

## Uncomment this if you run more than one Tor relay, and add the identity
## key fingerprint of each Tor relay you control, even if they're on
## different networks. You declare it here so Tor clients can avoid
## using more than one of your relays in a single circuit. See
## https://support.torproject.org/relay-operators/multiple-relays/
## However, you should never include a bridge's fingerprint here, as it would
## break its concealability and potentially reveal its IP/TCP address.
##
## If you are running multiple relays, you MUST set this option.
##
## Note: do not use MyFamily on bridge relays.
#MyFamily $keyid,$keyid,...

## Uncomment this if you want your relay to be an exit, with the default
## exit policy (or whatever exit policy you set below).
## (If ReducedExitPolicy, ExitPolicy, or IPv6Exit are set, relays are exits.
## If none of these options are set, relays are non-exits.)
#ExitRelay 1

## Uncomment this if you want your relay to allow IPv6 exit traffic.
## (Relays do not allow any exit traffic by default.)
#IPv6Exit 1

## Uncomment this if you want your relay to be an exit, with a reduced set
## of exit ports.
#ReducedExitPolicy 1

## Uncomment these lines if you want your relay to be an exit, with the
## specified set of exit IPs and ports.
##
## A comma-separated list of exit policies. They're considered first
## to last, and the first match wins.
##
## If you want to allow the same ports on IPv4 and IPv6, write your rules
## using accept/reject *. If you want to allow different ports on IPv4 and
## IPv6, write your IPv6 rules using accept6/reject6 *6, and your IPv4 rules
## using accept/reject *4.
##
## If you want to _replace_ the default exit policy, end this with either a
## reject *:* or an accept *:*. Otherwise, you're _augmenting_ (prepending to)
## the default exit policy. Leave commented to just use the default, which is
## described in the man page or at
## https://support.torproject.org/relay-operators
##
## Look at https://support.torproject.org/abuse/exit-relay-expectations/
## for issues you might encounter if you use the default exit policy.
##
## If certain IPs and ports are blocked externally, e.g. by your firewall,
## you should update your exit policy to reflect this -- otherwise Tor
## users will be told that those destinations are down.
##
## For security, by default Tor rejects connections to private (local)
## networks, including to the configured primary public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses,
## and any public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on any interface on the relay.
## See the man page entry for ExitPolicyRejectPrivate if you want to allow
## "exit enclaving".
##
#ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:* # allow irc ports on IPv4 and IPv6 but no more
#ExitPolicy accept *:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv4 and IPv6 as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy accept *4:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv4 only as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy accept6 *6:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv6 only as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed

## Bridge relays (or "bridges") are Tor relays that aren't listed in the
## main directory. Since there is no complete public list of them, even an
## ISP that filters connections to all the known Tor relays probably
## won't be able to block all the bridges. Also, websites won't treat you
## differently because they won't know you're running Tor. If you can
## be a real relay, please do; but if not, be a bridge!
##
## Warning: when running your Tor as a bridge, make sure than MyFamily is
## NOT configured.
#BridgeRelay 1
## By default, Tor will advertise your bridge to users through various
## mechanisms like https://bridges.torproject.org/. If you want to run
## a private bridge, for example because you'll give out your bridge
## address manually to your friends, uncomment this line:
#BridgeDistribution none

## Configuration options can be imported from files or folders using the %include
## option with the value being a path. This path can have wildcards. Wildcards are
## expanded first, using lexical order. Then, for each matching file or folder, the following
## rules are followed: if the path is a file, the options from the file will be parsed as if
## they were written where the %include option is. If the path is a folder, all files on that
## folder will be parsed following lexical order. Files starting with a dot are ignored. Files
## on subfolders are ignored.
## The %include option can be used recursively.
#%include /etc/torrc.d/*.conf




/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc

DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
DataDirectoryGroupReadable 1
User toranon
Log notice syslog






Please post your torrc config - without private and bridge data :) and how exactly you're using check.torproject.org - Tor does not proxify the whole host at startup by default, if you're expecting this out of the box

@AlexeyVesnin, I'm using the default configuration. I've added it to the post. Your second statement is probably the crux of the problem - how might I proxify Firefox or the whole host whilst it's running? I expected it to act somewhat similarly to Orbot for AOSP.

You need to utilize the Virtual network routing, we have already solved this situation in this question here Transparently Routing Traffic Through Tor

This is surprisingly complex. I can quite confidently state that I understand barely any of what the answer you cited states. Do you know whether a (compelling) reason exists for the proxy not functioning OS-wide by default?

@RokeJulianLockhart, Touché, your question is also long. The link in this answer points to another answer linking to: https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/doc/TransparentProxy - which answers your question: "Do official configuration instructions exist?", which warning against doing this if you are inexperienced. A simpler solution is offered there, if you don't want the complicated method.

@Rob, thanks again. That at least provides me with the name of what I want - a "transparent proxy". I'll rename this question to include it. Note that that URI is unfortunately archived though, and the formatting is beginning to break as GitLab updates. Seems like someone needs to find a new home for the wiki page.
